# How to tell kubectl to use different api groups

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I am trying to list down resources which is in different api group. I am running the below command

```
[jk@ome-esrs-adapter-master csadmin]# kubectl get issuers -n default
Error from server (NotFound): Unable to list "certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1, Resource=issuers": the server could not find the requested resource (get issuers.certmanager.k8s.io)
```

As you can see it is not listing any issuer which is in default space because it is searching in this api group "certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1" and acutal resource is in "cert-manager.io/v1alpha2" this API group so, I have specify api group in rest call and it is listing the issuer

```
[jk@ome-esrs-adapter-master csadmin]# curl http://localhost:8080/apis/cert-manager.io/v1alpha2/issuers | jq .
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   975  100   975    0     0  47140      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 48750
{
  "apiVersion": "cert-manager.io/v1alpha2",
  "items": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "cert-manager.io/v1alpha2",
      "kind": "Issuer",
      "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
          "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"cert-manager.io/v1alpha2\",\"kind\":\"Issuer\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"ca-issuer\",\"namespace\":\"default\"},\"spec\":{\"ca\":{\"secretName\":\"nginxsecret\"}}}\n"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2020-04-02T13:05:56Z",
        "generation": 1,
        "name": "ca-issuer",
        "namespace": "default",
        "resourceVersion": "67806",
        "selfLink": "/apis/cert-manager.io/v1alpha2/namespaces/default/issuers/ca-issuer",
        "uid": "2970a3e5-6d0c-4f2b-964d-4598be9beaa3"
      },
      "spec": {
        "ca": {
          "secretName": "nginxsecret"
        }
      },
      "status": {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "lastTransitionTime": "2020-04-02T13:05:53Z",
            "message": "Signing CA verified",
            "reason": "KeyPairVerified",
            "status": "True",
            "type": "Ready"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "kind": "IssuerList",
  "metadata": {
    "continue": "",
    "resourceVersion": "284959",
    "selfLink": "/apis/cert-manager.io/v1alpha2/issuers"
  }
}
```

can anyone please help how to tell kubectl to look into diffrent API groups? Because I am sure that resource is there as rest api is working and when I reapply yaml file it says Issuer unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in dotted notation (Object.apiVersion.APIGroup), for e.g. deployments this way: `kubectl get deployments.v1.apps` In your case just try:

```
kubectl get issuer.v1alpha2.cert-manager.io -n=default
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.